# Airdrop seems to be missing on my Macbook Pro

Tags: macos, finder, network, airdrop

**System**:
MacBook Pro (15-inch, 2017)
macOS 10.13.6 (17G14033)

**Issue**: I cannot send files to my MacBook Pro from my iPhones using Airdrop. When I try to share a file from a iPhone to the Mac using AirDrop, the Mac just doesn't show up among the available users. I looked for AirDrop among the Finder Favorites, and it's not there:

[image]

[Following the instructions on this website](https://appletoolbox.com/qa-airdrop-is-missing/), I navigated to the Go menu in Finder, selected Go to Folder and pasted in this path:

```
/System/Library/CoreServices/Finder.app/Contents/Applications
```

This is what I see:

[image]

However, if I click on the AirDrop icon, I get this error message:

[image]

What is happening? Can you help me get AirDrop to work on my Mac?

**EDIT**: there's no AirDrop item in the Finder → Go menu

[image]

the <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>⌘</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd> shortcut doesn't seem to do anything at all, and finally both WiFi and BlueTooth are turned on:

[image]

Comment: In the Finder menu bar go to Go → AirDrop, or use the keyboard shortcut Shift + Command + R and see if you are able to turn on AirDrop. Also check if you have Bluetooth and Wi-Fi turned on.

Comment: @NimeshNeema see my edits to the question. None of your suggestions seem to work.

Comment: Is there any personal information in the contents of the app AirDrop? I did some digging in the package contents but couldn't find any. If it has no personal information, I can upload and attach the airdrop app, and you can save a backup of the corrupt app and paste my app in.

Comment: I have the same issue. My macBook is managed by my company, not sure if they disabled it because of security concerns

Comment: I'm experiencing the same issue on my work MacBook. AirDrop just disappeared from everywhere and I get "The operation can’t be completed because the item can’t be found" when I try to launch the AirDrop app from Spotlight Search (Cmd+Space).
I thought that it may be caused by some security policy enforced by organization's IT. But other employees do have AirDrop working.

Comment: Yeah, I think it's a company management thing. Just got a replacement laptop and now have the same issue 